# compare with two string array iphone

Tags: iphone, arrays

i have created a quiz application for iphone Where i added multiple selection option.
Suppose correct ans is ABC and selected ans is AC. Both are string array. how can i compare if the ans is correct or wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
    NSString* rgtAns = @"ABC";//right answer
    NSString* ans = @"Ac";//current answer

    rgtAns = [rgtAns uppercaseString];//uppercase the string
    ans = [ans uppercaseString];//if the answer letters are uppercase, you do not need this

    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: rgtAns] invertedSet];
    NSString *filtered = [[ans componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    BOOL isRight = [ans isEqualToString:filtered];
    NSLog(@"%d",isRight);
```

Answer (score 0):

in iOS you should use NSString (or its mutable version, NSMutableString) to work with strings, NSString has a method named `isEqualToString:` That helps you compare two string objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if ([originalAnswer isEqualToString:userAnswerToCompare]){
   //do some processing here
    }
```